# How to force regular expressions to not include 'e' on numerics?

Tags: c#, regex, blazor

I have the following regular expression declared. I just want 0 to 9 accepted, I do not want decimal points or 'e' for large numbers.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\s]*$")]
 public int PalletsQty { get; set; }
```

How do I adjust this expression so that the decimal point and 'e' cannot be entered?

To put a bit more context on my question, it's a blazor app and I am using Blazorstrap.

I have removed the regex against the model as I realised that this is being overridden by Blazorstrap:

```
 <BSInput InputType="InputType.Number" @bind-Value="Booking.PalletsQty" @onkeydown="@NumericOnly"></BSInput>

private void NumericOnly(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Code == "KeyE")
    {
        
    }
}
```

So it's now what I should place in the 'if' block to prevent the 'e' from being accepted.

Comment: Your regex should already do what you want. What is the problem you have?

Comment: I don't think you can apply a regex validator to an int field

Comment: `[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$")]` - one or more digits in `0..9` range, say `1`, `0256`, `39`; `[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]$")]` - any single digit in `0..9` range, say `0`, `1`, but not `123`

Comment: @SimonC no it doesn't i can enter '.' and 'e' as well

Comment: @DavidG the above restricts me to 0 to 9, '-', '.', 'e' values as an example I can enter 13456.34e

Comment: If you remove the attribute, nothing will change though. That attribute won't work on an integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging it was as simple as:

```
onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
```

to the <BSInput element